# Zoom in combined chart (Pareto) not working in QlikView 11

Tags: qlikview, pareto-chart

I have a combined chart (Pareto) and what I am trying to do is zooming the selected area by dragging and dropping mouse pointer but it is not working.

However I have another line chart and it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

The problem was "Read only" property was checked in chart-properties general tab. Unchecking it worked!